# system cron not running intended process scheduled for execution

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, cron

I have node server that I want to restart whenever it stopped. For this case  I setup system cron on ubuntu server to execute a simple bash script that will track node server every minute and log the server status. Now this cron   trigger this bash script and logs relevant status every minute but node server doesn't execute(Using simple linux command I can check if node server running or not). When manually running that bash script node server starts but something happening when cron executes that script. I am trying to fix this meanwhile any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `forever` for auto-start of your node app? https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Comment: Did you check the logs in `/var/log/syslog`?

Comment: After trying multiple options this solution works for me. Declaring **PATH** and **SHELL** in cron. I am using /bin/bash So explicitly adding these two solve this issue. @Samarth yes syslogs list script execution indeed.

Comment: @ssemilla Although I didn't tried this node tool but using forever in CLI mode good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing this with `cron` i think you have to use `spervisor` in order to keep the process running check this [supervisor website](http://supervisord.org/)